# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame when using pd.filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice

I have seen this a million times, I am somehow chaining indexes and am getting a setting with copy warning.  The code I am using is below:

```
toEmail['median'] = np.nanmedian(toEmail.filter(like = 'foo_'), axis = 1)
```

I am guessing that it has to do with filter is creating some slice but I am not sure.  I have tried the following, neither of which worked.

```
toEmail['median'] = np.nanmedian(toEmail.filter(like = 'foo_').copy(deep=True), axis = 1)
toEmail['median'] = list(np.nanmedian(toEmail.filter(like = 'foo_'), axis = 1))
```

--- EDIT ---
Per the comments I got this dataframe from this:

```
toEmail = fullDf[['foo_1', 'foo_2', 'bar_1', 'bar_2']]
```

and adding the copy here fixes the issues

```
toEmail = fullDf[['foo_1', 'foo_2', 'bar_1', 'bar_2']].copy()
```

Comment: It looks like problem is on the left hand side of the assignment. How was toEmail obtained?

Comment: @matusko updated thanks

Comment: [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835483/confusion-re-pandas-copy-of-slice-of-dataframe-warning?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)