# Create duplicate column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I want to duplicate a column which has numerical character in the start position. ie(**1**stfloor)

In simple term, I want to convert column 1stfloor to FirstFloor

```
df
    1stfloor
    456 
    784
    746
    44 
    9984
```

Tried using the below code,

```
df['FirstFloor'] = df['1stfloor']
```

encountered with below error message:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

**Expected output:**

df

```
FirstFloor 
456 
784
746
44 
9984
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion re: pandas copy of slice of dataframe warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835483/confusion-re-pandas-copy-of-slice-of-dataframe-warning)

Answer (score 26):

```
df['FirstFloor'] = df['1stfloor'] 
df['FirstFloor'] = df.loc[:, '1stfloor']
```

Both worked!