# copying column data into another dataframe using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

after spliting x_train ,y_train .

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3)
print(x_train.shape,y_train.shape)
(354, 13) (354,)
```

Again I need to join `ytrain` column to `xtrain` .Price is new column

`x_train['Price']=y_train` but this does not work

I am trying to use iloc like following but it gives warning

```
x_train['price']=y_train.iloc[0:354]
```

please help me out regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that warning because `x_train` is a view of `X`. Using an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,4)),
columns=['x1','x2','x3','y'])
X = df[['x1','x2','x3']]
Y = df[['y']]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3)
```

You can see:

```
x_train._is_view
True
```

If I try to run your code, I get the same warning.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835483/confusion-re-pandas-copy-of-slice-of-dataframe-warning) about views of a data frame and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) on dealing with the warning. What you can do make a copy if you don't think it's an issue:

```
x_train = x_train.copy()
x_train['Price'] = y_train
```

Or use insert:

```
x_train.insert(x_train.shape[1],"Price",y_train)
```